# Computer generate heat almost instantly after power up?

Tags: overheating

I have HP G42 PC here, and recently it's frequently give out emergency notice on boot saying that the CPU was overheated. Even if it was switched on recently after the notice appears, it barely stay switched on less than 20 seconds. One thing I noticed if the PC was left cool down for several hours and switched back on, it generates heat almost instantly. Is this normal? I have other 2 PC's and usually it takes them a while to generate heat even after total cooled down state.

Comment: CPUs are mercurial, and heat up almost instantly, which is why they require active cooling. Your cooling is only working if it cools down equally fast when the load is reduced. During BIOS load, the computers full set of power management capabilities are not yet available, so its not uncommon to turn it on, hit 45-50C during bios load, and then cool off to more reasonable idle temps after boot. HDD temps especially are very slow to rise and slow to fall, but a CPU can change temperature in excess of 20C in a second or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the fan work? Have you taken the cover off to check? If you have an external fan, you can use it to blow into the desktop box (take the cover off), then if you have enough time, you can run some tests.

**CPU tests**:

- [CPU test 1](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)
- [CPU test 2](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2297/techpowerup-gpu-z-v0-7-4/mirrors)
- [CPU test 3](http://realtemp.en.lo4d.com/)

**Fan test**:

- [Fan test 1](http://speedfan.en.lo4d.com/)

Download [**Hirensboot cd**](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) or [**UBCD**](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) to one of your other computers, burn it to CD/DVD and set the problem computer to boot from CD first.

Insert and try to test or check the CPU, fan, hard drive, etc. The CD's system contents and how to use them are listed on each programs home website.

If you can not get the computer to run long enough to do any testing, you may have to take it to a computer shop and have the components tested.

Comment: Well I have table top fan to backup sometimes the PC still says overheat. Only by some chance of luck it will stay on but who knows how long. I will give hirensboot cd a try. Thanks!